# jQuery showing Unexpected token ;

Tags: jquery

I was given the code below for an answer to another question I asked but its giving me `Unexpected token ;`.  I have a feeling its missing closing `)` but I have added them in and its still not resolved what have I missed.

Why am I getting `Unexpected token ;`?

**Code:**

```
<script>
    jQuery(window).on('click', '.add_to_cart.button', function() {
        call_ajax_add_to_quotelist(add_to_quotelist_ajax_url, $(this).data('id');
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Count the number of open and close braces and parens. You're missing at least two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing closing `)` on the function call and at the end of the handler

```
jQuery(window).on('click', '.add_to_cart.button', function() {
    call_ajax_add_to_quotelist(add_to_quotelist_ajax_url, $(this).data('id')); //here
}); //and here
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is missing two closing parenthesis `)` on this line:

```
<script>
  jQuery(window).on('click', '.add_to_cart.button', function() {
    call_ajax_add_to_quotelist(add_to_quotelist_ajax_url, $(this).data('id')); /added )
  }); //added );
</script>
```